# How to combine this script with yajira datatables in laravel 8, to work with both date range and type of data(sql tables)

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

I have a problem when it come to fetching data from database in various tables based on table name send by selecting on drop down option and date range combination.

on the form I have three field which are from_date, to__date and type of data where there is three drop down sales, product and purchase

when I choose dates and one option maybe sales then the results should be based on sales data between that range look my script  below i not working.

On submit event

```
      $("#reports").on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

          $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              }
          });

          $.ajax({
              url: "{{route('reports')}}",
              type: 'POST',
              data: new FormData(this),
              dataType: 'JSON',
              contentType: false,
              cache: false,
              processData: false,
              encode: true,
          }).done( function (data) {
                    
              if(data.success == false) {
                  //get form validation message from the server.....
              }else{
                 ///Give specific yajira datatable based on the rquest....
              }
          });
     });
```

here a sample yarira which work on it self

```
$('#sales-report').DataTable({
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": {
    "url": "{{ url('reports') }}",
    "dataType": 'JSON',
    "type": 'get',
    "data":{_token: "{{csrf_token()}}" }
},
columns: [
    { data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
    { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
    { data: 'quantity', name: 'quantity' },            
});
```

So I want to combine them, It means that, you choose date range, and data type then it come with the specifuc table with the specifict data from the three table